# Stop computer output to display

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'd like to be able to stop a computer outputting to the display or be able to hide this output temporarily. I've used a VNC application called AnyPlace that allows the controlling computer to hide the output to the monitor and stop keyboard input, but I can't work out how they did this. 
As you can still control the computer from the remote app I'm assuming they don't just load an application with a black screen. I thought about doing this but I can't guarantee I'll be the topmost application apparently.
I need to be able to hide the screen whilst I use a control system to close on application and open another in the background and then restore the output.

Comment: From your requirements, it sounds like rendering doesn't actually have to take place in the interim?  Might be much easier than what VNC has to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some programs use DPMS to force the monitor into power-saving mode.  Others might use a HUD overlay to draw on top of the screen without actually having a window (these are frequently used alongside volume control keys, etc).  In Windows, you can use the "window station / desktop" GUI containment APIs to switch to a whole other desktop temporarily.